# Give mobile application access to Symfony secured path (via post)

Tags: php, symfony

How could I give access to mobile application (apk) to my website to a secured path (i.e. a path that you must be logged in to get there). I will need this for my project, but now I'm building a website.

I will build mobile app as soon as I complete web app, so I'm asking in advance because I don't want to rebuild security system after I complete it and find out, that it's not possible to do that. So I'm just asking for tips which I would expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the mobile app, you need to create an API to post or get data. You can use [FOSRestBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html). Then you need to secure this API via AccessToken. So the mobile app need an accesstoken to access to this API. It can get one after authentication. You can use [FOSOAuthServerBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) to secure your API.

The process is not that easy. So you need to read the documentation and Make some research before building your mobile app.